# pl/sql program output order is wrong

Tags: oracle, plsql, prompt

This is my table structure

```
create table questionnaire
(
  qno         int primary key,
  ques        varchar2(50),
  option1     varchar2(10),
  option2     varchar2(10),
  option3     varchar2(10),
  correct_ans varchar2(10)
);

create table user_ans
(
  user_id int primary key,
  ansq1   varchar2(15),
  ansq2   varchar2(15),
  ansq3   varchar2(15),
  status  varchar2(8),
  marks   number(3)
);
```

This is my pl/sql code. I'm trying to fetch and display the questions from my questionnaire, prompt the user for his answers, check if its the correct answer and calculate marks accordingly and update my table. But the following program prompts the user for input before displaying the questions. I'm using oracle 9i.

```
declare
  cursor q_cur is
    select qno, ques, option1, option2, option3
    from questionnaire 
    order by qno;
  cursor eval is
    select user_id, ansq1, ansq1, ansq3
    from user_ans;
  vq_rec    q_cur%rowtype;
  v_qno     questionnaire.qno%type;
  v_ques    questionnaire.ques%type;
  v_option1 questionnaire.option1%type;
  v_option2 questionnaire.option2%type;
  v_option3 questionnaire.option3%type;
  v_ans     varchar2(15);
  v_userid  user_ans.user_id%type;
  v_ansq1   user_ans.ansq1%type;
  v_ansq2   user_ans.ansq2%type;
  v_ansq3   user_ans.ansq3%type;
begin
  open q_cur;
  loop
    fetch q_cur into v_qno, v_ques, v_option1, v_option2, v_option3;
    exit when q_cur%notfound;
    dbms_output.put_line(
      v_qno || '. ' || v_ques);
    dbms_output.put_line(
      'a. ' || v_option1 || ' ' ||
      'b. ' || v_option2 || ' ' ||
      'c. ' || v_option3);
  end loop;
  close q_cur;
  open eval;
  fetch eval into v_userid, v_ansq1, v_ansq2, v_ansq3;
  insert into user_ans
    (user_id, ansq1, ansq2, ansq3)
  values
    (&v_userid, '&v_ansq1', '&v_ansq2', '&v_ansq3');
  close eval;
end;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
  insert into user_ans(user_id, ansq1, ansq2, ansq3)
                values(v_userid,v_ansq1, v_ansq, v_ansq3);
```

`&variable`s are set as *macro* value before even attempted to compile! SO they are prompted to you at the very beginning.

To use those variables in your `INSERT`, just use the name.

**EDIT:** If you look for *Interactive* I/O in PL/SQL, It is not possible!